# How to call one Fragment Class Method from another Fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi i am very new for android in my app i have created Two fragments they are "MenuFragment" and "TextFragment" ok that's fine

But in my TextFragment i have one Method so that i want call that method from my MenuFragment class

public void change(String txt, String txt1) method i want to call from my MenuFragment

how can i do this please help me some

### TextFragment:-

```
public class TextFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView text,vers;

    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return view;
    }

    public void change(String txt, String txt1){

        text.setText(txt);
        vers.setText(txt1);
    }
}
```

### MenuFragment:-

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {

    String[] AndroidOS = new String[]{"Cupcake", "Donut", "Eclair", "Froyo", "Gingerbread", "Honeycomb", "Ice Cream SandWich", "Jelly Bean", "KitKat", "Jelly Bean", "KitKat"};
    String[] Version = new String[]{"1.5", "1.6", "2.0-2.1", "2.2", "2.3", "3.0-3.2", "4.0", "4.1-4.3", "4.4", "4.1-4.3", "4.4"};

  @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    }
}
```

Comment: you can use static method .

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100338/how-to-call-method-of-one-fragment-from-another-fragment-class-in-android u can find your answer from here

Comment: please tell me through code i am very begginer for android

Comment: kishan i am not understand can u update my code please,i am very new for android

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.

**For TextFragment:-**

```
public class TextFragment  extends Fragment{

public static TextView text,vers;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

public static void change(String txt, String txt1){

    text.setText(txt);
    vers.setText(txt1);
}
}
```

**For MenuFragment:-**

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {

ListView list;
Button button1, button2;
String[] AndroidOS = new String[]{"Cupcake", "Donut", "Eclair", "Froyo", "Gingerbread", "Honeycomb", "Ice Cream SandWich", "Jelly Bean", "KitKat", "Jelly Bean", "KitKat"};
String[] Version = new String[]{"1.5", "1.6", "2.0-2.1", "2.2", "2.3", "3.0-3.2", "4.0", "4.1-4.3", "4.4", "4.1-4.3", "4.4"};


  @Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
         TextFragment.change(AndroidOS[position],Version[position]);  
}
}
```

I hope This will help you.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its not a good idea to leave communication betweeen two fragments like this, because you are coupling the `fragments`; `TextFragment` should not know about methods from `MenuFragment` .

A better solution is described in here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

You must create `Activity` for these two `fragments` and make `call back` for comunication

Comment: so cant we call Textfragment that method from Menufragment?

Comment: It is irrelevant to Android to do such a thing... as i said above TextFragment should not know about methods from MenuFragment its just a pattern , you want to do this in a wrong way

Comment: so we must create two activities for those Textfragment and Menufragment and make communication b/w them right?

Comment: i am very new for android that's why i am strugling just two daya back i came into this technology

Comment: i think you must start read little documentation about Fragments And Activites , and how they communicate each other.. here another one guide with you can start http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This is irrelevant to Android as such, you need to get better understanding what are classes, objects, pointers, etc. -- all general OOP concepts.

To achieve your result you need to add a variable-pointer to an object of class TextFragment, which has to be properly initialized before use. Then just call:

```
if(varPtr!=null)
    varPtr.change(...);
```