# NullPointerException when calling a method from another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, instance, detach

I'm trying to follow a given example by the user [@sunil-sunny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100338/how-to-call-method-of-one-fragment-from-another-fragment-class-in-android), that says

> You can create static varibales like this
>
> ```
> static  FragmentB f;
>
> public static FragmentB newInstance(String title) {
>         FragmentB f = new FragmentB();
>         Bundle b = new Bundle();
>         b.putString(ARG_STATION_TITLE, title);
>         f.setArguments(b);
>         return f;
>     }
> ```
>
> You can use the `getInstance()` method to get the instance of
>   fragmentB
>
> ```
> public static FragmentB getInstance(){
>     return f;
> }
> ```
>
> Call like this `FragmentB.getInstance().methodinFragmentB();`

But for some reason I'm getting a `NullPointerException`.

In my Fragment, I have:

```
static ProductListFragment fragment;

    public static ProductListFragment newInstance(Category category, SubCategory subCategory) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable(AppConstants.FLAG_CATEGORY, category);
        args.putParcelable(AppConstants.FLAG_SUBCATEGORY, subCategory);
        ProductListFragment fragment = new ProductListFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public static ProductListFragment getInstance(){
        return fragment;
    }
```

And in another fragment I call a method `detachFragment` to close the current fragment and reload the list updated in the previous fragment:

```
// We close the fragment and reload the list
public void detachFragment(String tag) {
    transition.reverseTransition(100);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragmentManager
               .beginTransaction()
               .disallowAddToBackStack()
               .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up_bottom_sheet, R.anim.slide_down_bottom_sheet)
               .remove(fragment)
               .commitNow();

        ProductListFragment.getInstance().reloadProducts(); // Reload Fragment
    }
}
```

Logcat sais that the next line return a Null:

```
...
ProductListFragment.getInstance().reloadProducts(); // Reload Fragment
...
```

Comment: Can you also share stacktrace?

Comment: check this line `ProductListFragment fragment = new ProductListFragment();`
 and remove `ProductListFragment`

Comment: Very clear `fragment = null` inside `ProductListFragment`

Comment: Do you ever call `newInstance`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

when you call `ProductListFragment.getInstance().reloadProducts();` you are getting the `static ProductListFragment fragment` as a return from this function however `static ProductListFragment fragment` is no where initialised which returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code

```
static ProductListFragment fragment;
public static ProductListFragment newInstance(Category category, SubCategory subCategory) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable(AppConstants.FLAG_CATEGORY, category);
    args.putParcelable(AppConstants.FLAG_SUBCATEGORY, subCategory);
//Replace this line 
   // ProductListFragment fragment = new ProductListFragment();
//with this
fragment = new ProductListFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public static ProductListFragment getInstance(){
    return fragment;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jaydeep Patel sais:

> check this line ProductListFragment fragment = new
>   ProductListFragment(); and remove ProductListFragment

I've remove the declaration of a new fragment ProductListFragment and it's working. I was initializing 2 times the same variable (same name).